# Почему, когда я указываю путь к python3 в файле, он все равно обрабатывает через python2?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu, pyinstaller

Я работаю с pyinstaller-3.2, который интерпретирует фалы через python2.7, а мне нужен python3.
Указываю путь к python3

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
```

Даже

```py
#!/usr/bin/python3
```

Но, при сборке, он просто не читает указатель пути к python3

```sh
./pyinstaller.py --onefile main.py
```

А выдает ошибку: по понятным причинам

```
  File "/home/pepe/PyInstaller-3.2/main.py", line 2
    print('Hello', end=' ')
                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

файла main.py:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
print('Hello', end=' ')
```

с использованием интерпретатора python3

```sh
python3 -m PyInstaller *args
```

выдает ошибку

```
107 INFO: PyInstaller: 3.2
108 INFO: Python: 3.8.10
116 INFO: Platform: Linux-5.15.0-57-generic-x86_64-with-glibc2.29
117 INFO: wrote /home/pepe/PyInstaller-3.2/*args/*args.spec
119 INFO: UPX is not available.
120 INFO: Extending PYTHONPATH with paths
['/home/pepe/PyInstaller-3.2', '/home/pepe/PyInstaller-3.2/*args']
120 INFO: checking Analysis
120 INFO: Building Analysis because out00-Analysis.toc is non existent
120 INFO: Initializing module dependency graph...
121 INFO: Initializing module graph hooks...
122 INFO: Analyzing base_library.zip ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/runpy.py", line 194, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/home/pepe/PyInstaller-3.2/PyInstaller/__main__.py", line 97, in <module>
    run()
  File "/home/pepe/PyInstaller-3.2/PyInstaller/__main__.py", line 90, in run
    run_build(pyi_config, spec_file, **vars(args))
  File "/home/pepe/PyInstaller-3.2/PyInstaller/__main__.py", line 46, in run_build
    PyInstaller.building.build_main.main(pyi_config, spec_file, **kwargs)
  File "/home/pepe/PyInstaller-3.2/PyInstaller/building/build_main.py", line 788, in main
    build(specfile, kw.get('distpath'), kw.get('workpath'), kw.get('clean_build'))
  File "/home/pepe/PyInstaller-3.2/PyInstaller/building/build_main.py", line 734, in build
    exec(text, spec_namespace)
  File "<string>", line 6, in <module>
  File "/home/pepe/PyInstaller-3.2/PyInstaller/building/build_main.py", line 212, in __init__
    self.__postinit__()
  File "/home/pepe/PyInstaller-3.2/PyInstaller/building/datastruct.py", line 178, in __postinit__
    self.assemble()
  File "/home/pepe/PyInstaller-3.2/PyInstaller/building/build_main.py", line 316, in assemble
    self.graph = initialize_modgraph(
  File "/home/pepe/PyInstaller-3.2/PyInstaller/depend/analysis.py", line 560, in initialize_modgraph
    graph.import_hook(m)
  File "/home/pepe/PyInstaller-3.2/PyInstaller/lib/modulegraph/modulegraph.py", line 906, in import_hook
    q, tail = self._find_head_package(parent, name, level)
  File "/home/pepe/PyInstaller-3.2/PyInstaller/lib/modulegraph/modulegraph.py", line 990, in _find_head_package
    q = self._safe_import_module(head, qname, parent)
  File "/home/pepe/PyInstaller-3.2/PyInstaller/depend/analysis.py", line 208, in _safe_import_module
    return super(PyiModuleGraph, self)._safe_import_module(
  File "/home/pepe/PyInstaller-3.2/PyInstaller/lib/modulegraph/modulegraph.py", line 1210, in _safe_import_module
    module = self._load_module(
  File "/home/pepe/PyInstaller-3.2/PyInstaller/lib/modulegraph/modulegraph.py", line 1295, in _load_module
    self._scan_code(m, co, co_ast)
  File "/home/pepe/PyInstaller-3.2/PyInstaller/lib/modulegraph/modulegraph.py", line 1460, in _scan_code
    self._scan_bytecode_stores(co, m)
  File "/home/pepe/PyInstaller-3.2/PyInstaller/lib/modulegraph/modulegraph.py", line 1505, in _scan_bytecode_stores
    name = co.co_names[oparg]
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

Comment: Вызовите  PyInstaller из 3-го питона, по типу - python3 -m PyInstaller *args

Answer (score 0):

Похоже, что **PyInstaller 3.2** использует **Python 2.7** для сборки вашего кода, несмотря на указание пути к **Python 3** в строке **shebang** вашего скрипта.

Решением этой проблемы будет использование самой последней версии **PyInstaller**, которая поддерживает **Python 3.x**.
Вы можете установить его через pip

```
pip install pyinstaller
```

Затем вы можете использовать команду **pyinstaller** для создания своего скрипта с нужной версией **Python**.

```
pyinstaller --onefile main.py
```

Он создаст исполняемый файл на основе версии **Python**, которая в данный момент активна в вашей системе.

Обратите внимание, что, поскольку вы используете более старую версию **Pyinstaller**, у вас могут возникнуть проблемы с версией **Python** или другими зависимостями. Если проблема не устранена, рекомендуется использовать самую последнюю версию **Pyinstaller**.